# I want to update table dynamically in html using python script

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have table in html which have dynamic number of rows. I have python script to provide values to table cells. I am sending a mail of html format but before i need to update html table.

```
<table style = "display: block;"> 
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$column1_value</td>
    <td>$column2_value</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style = "display: block;">
  <tr>
    <th>Dynamic column1</th>
    <th>Dynamic column2</th>
    <th>Dynamic column3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

These are the two tables which are declared.
I have written a python script and one of the table(First one) is updated as per code:-

```
filein = open( "path of above html file" )
tempSrc = Template( filein.read() )
msg = tempSrc.substitute({"column1_value":"value1_assigned","column2_value":"value2_assigned"})
```

Now, I want to update my second table as well but it has no fixed number of rows. I have data in json format like

```
{
    "values": {
       [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]
    }
}
```

`Json` `key`-`values` has `array/list` as `value`.

I know javascript methods to update table dynamically using `insertRow`, `document.createElement` and `appendChild` to table but i want to achieve the same thing using `python` script.

Kindly help in achieving the purpose.
Feel free to ask question if problem is not clear to you.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup:  (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Use a proper template engine (jinja2 comes to mind).